# JavaScript displaying correct date from dates stored as UTC on server

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

I have dates stored in my database in UTC format and calling

```
element.createdDate = new Date(element.createdDate.toString());
```

results in displaying the wrong date.

calling

```
element.createdDate = new Date(element.createdDate.toUTCString());
```

returns nothing. How do I go about displaying the correct time from UTC?

[image]

Comment: You're not providing enough information here for us to help you.  You say that you have data in your db in UTC, but then you show what appears to be a JS `Date` object.  How did you get there?  What data was sent to your JS code? how did you parse it to get a `Date` object?  Also, you have the output apparently also as a `Date` object.  Is that what you expected?  If not, what output did you expect?

Comment: Also, be sure you understand how the `Date` object works - it tracks UTC internally.  Some of the functions stay in UTC (like `toUTCString` or `getUTCHours`), and some of the functions convert to local time `(like `toString` or `getHours`).  If you just `console.log` the object without explicitly calling a function that emits a string, the implementation is undefined and varies across browsers (some give local time, some give UTC time).

Comment: Date is the built in Date from angular/core. element is just each iteration from a forEach loop and createdDate is the UTC date stored in mongo. ill add a picture of the full function

Comment: removed the picture, posted the code

Comment: Yes, but you took away the sample output also.  Please paste that as text as well.

Comment: sorry, put it back

Comment: Is `element.depositDate` a string or a Date? If it is a Date, log it using `toISOString()` rather than `toString()` or `getUTCDate()` or anything else, then compare the values. If it's a string, then you don't need `toString()` and `new Date()` will work.

Comment: Please post text or code, not images. Not everyone can see images and text is much easier to copy.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your json response contains a string valued which are in ISO8601 format in UTC, and then you are creating `Date` objects from them.

This part of your code is fine:

```
if (element.createdDate) element.createdDate = new Date(element.createdDate.toString());
```

- You parse the string, and the resulting `Date` object is correct.
- However, you don't need to use `.toString()` here, as the value is already a string.  That is redundant.

This part of your code is the problem:

```
console.log("javascript date: " + new Date(element.depositDate.getUTCDate().toString()));
```

- The `getUTCDate` function returns just the date of the month.  Don't use that.
- No matter what you do to create the `Date` object, ultimately you create a `Date` object and you're relying upon an implicit string conversion to output it.  This will have different behavior in different browsers.

Consider `console.log(new Date())`:

- In Chrome, this logs something like `Fri Mar 17 2017 12:14:29 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)` on my computer.  This is as if I called `console.log(new Date().toString());`  It is in an RFC 2822 like format (but not quite), and is represented in local time.
- In Firefox, this logs something like `2017-03-17T19:14:46.535Z`.  This is as if I called `console.log(new Date().toISOString());`  It is in ISO8601 format, and is represented in UTC.

The point is, don't rely on implicit undefined behavior.  If you must work with `Date` objects, then you should use `console.log(element.createdDate.toISOString())` to see the ISO8601 representation of the UTC time.

If you're going to be doing a lot of things with dates and times, you may prefer to use a library, such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which can make tasks such as this more clear.

Comment: If it's a string value coming back from the database, then calling `getUTCDate()` on it should fail, not return the date of the month...

Comment: That's true.  Also, it wouldn't make the output shown in the picture, so I think the OP must have taken the output screenshot based on the code he showed in [the earlier screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgUjT.png) before removing it in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

> I have dates stored in my database in UTC format and calling
>
> ```
> element.createdDate = new Date(element.createdDate.toString());
> ```
>
> results in displaying the wrong date.

`2016-10-11T00:00:00Z` and `Mon Oct 10 2016 20:00:00 GMT-04:00 (EDT)` are exactly the same moment in time. The only difference is that one is displayed in ISO 8601 extended format with timezone offset 00:00 and the other is displayed in an RFC 2822 (like) format with timezone offset -04:00 (and assumes a locality in the EDT region).

> calling
>
> ```
> element.createdDate = new Date(element.createdDate.toUTCString());
> ```
>
> returns nothing.

That is unusual. Typically it would return either a string or an error, but without a working example or any code to provide context it's impossible to say why.

> How do I go about displaying the correct time from UTC?

You haven't specified what "correct" is. You are displaying a date and time for the same moment in time, just in a different format and time zone.